# Git-svn 'refs/remotes/tags' exists; cannot create

Tags: git-svn

I have a problem when trying to migrate the subversion repository to Git repository

I run by following command

```
git svn clone -s --ignore-paths="tags" svn://localhost/web .
```

and I got the error message as below,

```
branch_from: /branches/tags => /branches/tags/3.7
Found possible branch point: svn://localhost/web/branches/tags/3.7 => svn://localhost/web/tags/3.7, 15131
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/tags/3.7@15131
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: File not found: revision 101, path '/branches/tags/3.7'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
Found possible branch point: svn://localhost/web/branches/workspace_production_3.0 => svn://localhost/web/branches/tags/3.7, 10538
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/tags/3.7@15131) a7067c8515c17c7f0bf8c6390a785426a8de5b83
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
error: 'refs/remotes/tags' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/tags/3.7@15131'
fatal: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/tags/3.7@15131'.
update-ref -m r10539 refs/remotes/tags/3.7@15131 67f3c547c7dfac657fcfd7759746f44eb74b187f: command returned error: 128
```

actually I don't want to ignore any path, but seem like tags occurs the problem, so I put it to the ignore-path.

Do I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push: refs/heads/my/subbranch exists, cannot create](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630404/git-push-refs-heads-my-subbranch-exists-cannot-create)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my repository, there are the previous revision that contains non-standard repository form like /branches/tags , so, I fixed by re-create git rep with following command

```
git svn init -s --ignore-paths="^tags|^branches/tags" svn://localhost/web .
git svn fetch
```