# git push: refs/heads/my/subbranch exists, cannot create

Tags: git

Is this not possible to create somme sub-sub-folder in a repo on a server?

if i do:

```
git push origin dev/master
```

everything work find

but if i do

```
git push origin dev/sub/master
```

i got this:

```
error: 'refs/heads/dev/sub' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/dev/sub/master'
```

i checked with `git branch -r` and directly with ssh, there isn't dev/sub folder already created.

what's wrong?

Comment: What does git ls-remote origin return?

Comment: just add a dash like so: dev/master dev/master-/sub

Answer (score 281, accepted):

It's not a *folder* that exists, it's a *branch*.  (Well, there may be a folder/directory involved somewhere—or maybe not, as references get "packed" and stop existing as files within directories.)

- **If branch `b` exists, no branch named `b/anything` can be created.**
- **Likewise, if branch `dev/b` exists, `dev/b/c` cannot be created.**

This is a git internal limitation.  In this particular case, remote `origin` has a branch named `dev/sub` (regardless of whether you have it or not, the important thing is whether the remote has it).  In order to create, on `origin`, a branch named `dev/sub/master`, you must first delete the branch named `dev/sub` on `origin`:

```
git push origin :dev/sub
```

(Of course, deleting this branch may delete something important over there, so be sure you know what you are doing.  Generally, you might want to `git fetch origin` first, capturing their `dev/sub` as your `origin/dev/sub`.  You can then make a local branch named `dev/renamed-sub` pointing to the same commit, create `dev/renamed-sub` on the remote, delete the remote `dev/sub`, and then create `dev/sub/master` on the remote.)

---

If you can log in on the remote (the system that `origin` is hosted on), you can go into the repository over there and simply rename the local `dev/sub` branch.  (Based on comments below, I suspect that there's a broken auto-deploy script over there as well, which probably should be fixed to only deploy "deployable" branches, rather than everything that gets pushed.  But I am just guessing here.)

Comment: but why localy i can do it ?
git branch give me :
master
dev/master
dev/sub/master
dev/sub/branch2
etc

Comment: @user3458953: Because you locally don't have a `refs/heads/dev/sub`. You probably have `refs/remotes/origin/dev/sub`, the tracking ref for the branch at origin, but that is a different name, so it does not conflict. See, the namespaces for branches on different repositories are independent.

Comment: Furthermore, after deleting all branch on origin (exept master), i still can't create dev/sub/master

Comment: @user3458953: How did you delete the branches on `origin`?

Comment: Note that `git branch -r` only lists your local copies of remote branches.  `git fetch --prune origin` will update your local copies, so that `git branch -r` should show you the state of the remote.  Or, use `git ls-remote` to see the state of the remote, including all its branches.  (Git's terminology gets in the way here big time: there's a really big difference between a "remote branch" and a "branch on the remote", even though it sure *sounds* like those should be the same!)

Comment: ooookay thank! but now, this: git push origin :dev/sub give me this error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion. (i don't know what i do with this branch x))

Comment: Ah, in that case you're kind of stuck, unless you can log in on the system that `origin` is on.  The problem is that the `HEAD` reference in the git repo over there points to the same commit as the `dev/sub` branch, most likely because `HEAD` is a symbolic ref pointing to `dev/sub`.  This suggests there's an auto-deploy script on the remote, possibly a poorly-written one.  In one such case pushing a commit (even a dummy one) to `master` will make the auto-deploy script switch the remote repo to branch `master`, but it's really in need of fixing over there.

Comment: mh, there isn't auto-deploy script, but i create my remote repo with a git clone --bare, before a scp, when i only had the master branch. As i experienced git remote, i looked in one time and maybe touch accidentaly something that i will not have to touch xD. I gonna delete and recreate the repo. thank for all explanations!

Comment: You can of course delete and re-create it, but you don't *have* to: you can use regular `git branch` commands on a bare repo, and do things like `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master` to re-point `HEAD`.

Comment: Note that this isn't necessarily an internal git limitation, but more of a file system limitation. If only packed refs would be used for example, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Ikke: but that would be changing the internals to remove the limitation, which means it's an internal limitation, no? :-)  Also git could keep using unpacked refs: for instance, turn each ref name into a sha1, then store the original name and target of the ref in `.git/sharefs/cafeb0b...` (requires opening all unpacked refs to find their string forms, hence more expensive than current dir traversal).  Basically any internal change that would allow it, would allow it...

Comment: The limitation is on how they are stored, not how git internally processes them. I don't say it's a limitation at all that wouldn't require a change to overcome it. It's more of a concrete implementation limitation than a abstract conceptual limitation.

Comment: I guess we're just fussing over terminology here.  By "internal limitation" I mean it's something git could overcome without changing how anyone *uses* git.  An unqualified limitation would be something much more fundamental, such as, if someone breaks SHA1: while even this could be overcome (e.g., move to SHA256), the details of 40-character SHA-1s are exposed in, e.g., most hooks, so this limitation leaks into externals.

Comment: That's a weirdly irritating limitation, given you might want to have `release/1.1` and `release/1.2` with `release/1.1/hofix/prevent-upload-bork` & `release/1.1/hotfix/assure-user-of-competence`, etc. And the error message leads one here (thank you), rather than stating the limitation! But thank you for simple and clear explanation.

Comment: "This is a git internal limitation." -- OK, but why? Was some logic easier to implement this way? Or some tree-traversal? Or what?

Comment: @D.Kovács: by forbidding that case, Git can simply write reference hashes into files whose name is produced by treating the reference as a path name. If Git allowed both `refs/tags/foo` and `refs/tags/foo/2`, for instance, it would not be able to do this: it would need to implement its own key-value store. I think Git is going to be forced to implement its own key-value store anyway, but I do not know if they will remove the limitation then.

Comment: @torek can you give me an official link about this. I think it's really annoying. I read a post about [git name convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273695/git-branch-naming-best-practices).
I have 1 branch `a` and many submodule `a/b`, `a/c`, `a/d` will merge into `a` daily. How can i archive that while keeping `a` branch.

Comment: @ĐinhAnhHuy: I don't know of any formal documentation describing this limitation. Submodules, however, are in a completely separate name-space: submodule names and branch names should not collide in the same way that branch names and file names don't collide (i.e., they do, but you add a disambiguator: `git checkout -- master` means check out the *file* named `master`, rather than the branch name).

Comment: "If branch b exists, no branch named b/anything can be created." You save my life, thank you :D

Comment: "Likewise, if branch `dev/b` exists, `dev/b/c` cannot be created."
True. But this can be misinterpreted. Instead, if branch `dev/b` exists and branch `dev` does not exist, then `dev/c` can be created.

Answer (score 101):

I was in a state when I couldn't even fetch because my repo had info about non-existing remote branches I didn't even had checked out. 
I solved it by running combination (thanks @torek) of:

- `git branch -r` list local copies of remote branches
- `git ls-remote` list remote branches
- `git fetch --prune origin` update local copies of remote branches (**this actually didn't help me**)
- `git remote prune origin` remove info about removed remote branches (**this did**)

Comment: `git remote prune origin` was the single command I ran in order to resolve this error state. Misleading message indeed - in my case I was trying to push a "release/2.6.0" and I had removed the whole 'refs/remotes/origin/release*' dir - yet git kept complaining `error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/release/2.6.0': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/release/2.6.0': 'refs/remotes/origin/release' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/release/2.6.0'` whenever I tried push/pull/fetch

Comment: More explanation to walk through such a situation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76012255

Answer (score 64):

For me -->

Error =

```
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/release/wl/2.3': 'refs/heads/release/wl' 
exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/release/wl/2.3'
```

Solution =

```
$~ git update-ref -d refs/heads/release/wl
$~ git checkout release/wl/2.3
```

Comment: git update-ref -d refs/remotes... solved my problem to 'refs/remotes/origin/hotfix' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/hotfix/ISSUE...

Comment: It also fixed my problem.

Comment: I also got `error: 'refs/heads/develop' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables'` while trying to rename my local branch from `bugfix/sort-rows-of-common-tables` to `develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables` by running `git branch -m develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables`, having branch `develop`
already existing. Solved by running `git update-ref -d refs/heads/develop` and then `git branch -m develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables`, thanks sir!

Comment: However, now II cannot push that branch to remote because on remote it is giving me the same error it was giving me on local. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257792/cannot-push-branch-after-renaming-and-fixing-error-with-update-refs

Comment: Fixed the problem, especially for a person that doesn't want to do "git remote prune origin" in a company repo.

Answer (score 21):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630664/2590469) didn't help me because I didn't have a ref on the remote repo to delete - it was purely on my local! So if you're in that situation, here's what to do:

This is the issue I was facing:

```
$ git fetch origin
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/fix/sub-branch': 
'refs/remotes/origin/fix' exists; cannot create 
'refs/remotes/origin/fix/sub-branch'
From <repo URL>
 ! [new branch]      fix/sub-branch          -> origin/fix/sub-branch
 (unable to update local ref)
```

I tried the accepted answer's suggestion but got this:

```
$ git push origin :fix
error: unable to delete 'fix': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to <repo URL>
```

So the ref didn't even exist on `origin` - it was clearly just hanging around somewhere on my local repo. So I ran `$ git remote show me`, which produced:

```
Remote branches:
...
refs/remotes/origin/fix             stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
...
```

Which then made the solution clear:

```
$ git remote prune origin
Pruning origin
URL: <redacted>
 * [pruned] origin/fix
```

With this, the problem disappeared:

```
$ git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 2), reused 2 (delta 2), pack-reused 3
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From <repo URL>
 * [new branch]      fix/sub-branch          -> origin/fix/sub-branch
```

Comment: Yep, same issue as you ran into and `git remote prune origin` fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I understand this is already answered, but it did not worked for me. I did not cared for local changes as it was already pushed up but having issues pulling back. In my case, we changed halfway between having "hotfix" as branch to folder system having parent folder as "hotfix".

-- hotfix
----hotfix/1234_bug
----hotfix/3456_bug

So I was getting following error:

```
Fetching from origin Error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/hotfix/1234_bug': 'refs/remotes/origin/hotfix' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/hotfix'
```

After searching for similar errors finally I found solution on a discussion thread [here](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/5438).

```
git remote prune origin
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this command to fix it:

```bash
git gc
```

to run a number of housekeeping tasks within the current repository and remove unreachable objects (by invoking `git prune` and `git fsck --unreachable`).

Read more: `git help gc` ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)) and `git help prune` ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune)).

> git-gc - Cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository

> git-prune - Prune all unreachable objects from the object database

Answer (score 3):

Rename `dev/sub` to `dev/sub/something`, then you can create branch `dev/sub/master`.

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As a windows user, none of the solutions thus far solved the problem for me. The reason I was seeing this error was because (using the OP's branch names) I was trying to create a branch `dev/sub` but someone else had created a branch called `Dev` and as we all know, windows has a case insensitive file system.

So when windows tried to pull down `dev/sub` it was first trying to create the folder `dev`, but it couldn't because `Dev` already existed.

The solution was to delete the `Dev` branch locally and remotely with `git branch -d Dev && git push origin :Dev`. A `git pull` after this ran fine.

Another lesson going forward, branch names should always be lowercase to avoid this kind of gotcha's.

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, check that your repo system does not have limitations for branch names. In my case, you could only create branches that start with `SD-<number>`. Any other naming would give you just a generic:

```
remote: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/mybranch': 'refs/heads/mybranch/environment-variables' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/mybranch'
To git.example.com:project/repository.git
 ! [remote rejected] mybranch -> mybranch (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.example.com:project/repository.git'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "update-ref delete refs/tags"
log="git-update-ref-errors.log"
script="./git-update-ref-exist-tags-delete.sh"
git_command="git update-ref -d refs/tags"

echo "log errors from ${git_command} to ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | > ${log}
echo "show errors to ${log}"
cat ${log}
echo create ${script}
touch ${script}
echo "add execute (+x) permissions to ${script}"
chmod +x ${script}
echo "generate ${script} from errors log ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | grep 'exists' | sed -n "s:.*\: 'refs/tags/\(.*\)' exists;.*:git tag -d '\1':p" >> ${script}
echo "execute ${script}"
${script}

echo fetch
log="git-fetch-errors.log"
script="./git-fetch-exist-tags-delete.sh"
git_command="git fetch"
echo "log errors from ${git_command} to ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | > ${log}
echo "show errors from ${log}"
cat ${log}
echo create ${script}
touch ${script}
echo "add execute (+x) permissions to ${script}"
chmod +x ${script}
echo "generate ${script} from errors log ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | grep 'exists' | sed -n "s:.*\: 'refs/tags/\(.*\)' exists;.*:git tag -d '\1':p" >> ${script}
echo "execute ${script}"
${script}
git fetch

echo pull
log="git-pull-errors.log"
script="./git-pull-exist-tags-delete.sh"
git_command="git pull"
echo "log errors from ${git_command} to ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | > ${log}
echo "show errors from ${log}"
cat ${log}
echo create ${script}
touch ${script}
echo "add execute (+x) permissions to ${script}"
chmod +x ${script}
echo "generate ${script} from errors log ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | grep 'exists' | sed -n "s:.*\: 'refs/tags/\(.*\)' exists;.*:git tag -d '\1':p" >> ${script}
echo "execute ${script}"
${script}
git pull

echo push
log="git-push-errors.log"
script="./git-push-exist-tags-delete.sh"
git_command="git push"
echo "log errors from ${git_command} to ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | > ${log}
echo "show errors from ${log}"
cat ${log}
echo create ${script}
touch ${script}
echo "add execute (+x) permissions to ${script}"
chmod +x ${script}
echo "generate ${script} from errors log ${log}"
${git_command} 2>&1 | grep 'exists' | sed -n "s:.*\: 'refs/tags/\(.*\)' exists;.*:git tag -d '\1':p" >> ${script}
echo "execute ${script}"
${script}
git push
```

The script above will log errors to XXX-errors.log and fix them by generating and running a XXX-exist-tags-delete.sh automatically from the XXX-errors.log using the following commands:

1. git update-ref -d refs/tags
2. git fetch
3. git pull
4. git push

Answer (score 1):

First I removed the branches that weren't present in remote but were affecting me locally:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Then I proceeded on to delete any references that were affecting me from creating my `develop` branch (In my case I had two such references, so I ran it twice):

```
git update-ref -d refs/heads/develop/dummy
```

Lastly, set the correct tracking reference:

```
git checkout --track origin/develop
```

Answer (score 0):

`git remote prune origin` fixed the issue for me

Answer (score -2):

```
git checkout -b hotfix/my-new-branch

ga
gm "my commit"

gp --set-upstream origin hotfix/subscribers-function
```