# git branches named "foo" and "foo/bar" don't work?

Tags: git

In a possibly misguided attempt at organizing branch names, I attempted to make two branches where one was a "subpath" of the other — say, "foo" and "foo/bar" — and git refused to make the second one:

```
error: 'refs/heads/foo' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/foo/bar'
```

Considering how the `.git/refs/heads` is organized, at least on my system, this makes sense — a branch is a file in `heads`, but slashes in branch names create directories, and a single entry can't be a file and a directory at the same time.

However, I can't find this limitation mentioned in the documentation.  Is it a formal restriction, or is it just an implementation limit that everyone learns to avoid?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+%27refs%2Fheads%2F%27+exists%3B+cannot+create+%27refs%2Fheads%2F%27

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527452/4880924

Comment: When you put a slash in a branch name git creates a folder. So foo/bar would create a folder foo with a file bar inside it. However it seems git won’t let you do this if a branch name (a file with that name) already exists.

Comment: I agree that this is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630404/git-push-refs-heads-my-subbranch-exists-cannot-create, but @chris-yungmann's answer directly answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is an undocumented implementation limitation of the files backend and packed ref store backend. In theory the git codebase can be extended with additional backends that do not have the same limitation. See [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org//msg116444.html) mailing list thread for some discussion.