# Can't create branches with slashes in Git if left part exists and commits also exists

Tags: git

I was using branches with slashes for some time, but suddenly found that I can't create them in some circumstances

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dimskraft/tests/git-slash-branch/.git/

$ git checkout -b my-branch
Switched to a new branch 'my-branch'

$ git status
On branch my-branch

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

$ git checkout -b my-branch/sub-branch
Switched to a new branch 'my-branch/sub-branch'

$ touch myfile.txt
$ git add myfile.txt 
$ git commit -m "added myfile.txt"
[my-branch/sub-branch (root-commit) 9be5cc5] added myfile.txt
...

$ git checkout -b my-branch/sub-branch/aaa
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/my-branch/sub-branch/aaa': 'refs/heads/my-branch/sub-branch' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/my-branch/sub-branch/aaa'

$ git status
On branch my-branch/sub-branch
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Why and is it possible to overcome?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+cannot+lock+ref+exists+cannot+create

Comment: Note that an "orphan branch" doesn't actually exist until there are commits on it, so it *is* possible to create `b/sub` while on the orphan branch `b`. Creating a commit while on orphan branch `b` causes branch `b` to actually exist (no longer be an orphan branch), after which Git forbids `b/sub`. Git is programmed to forbid this so that it won't get itself in trouble later, even though there are *some* cases where it *could* work.

Comment: Git needs to stop storing branch names in simple OS files, to fix this and other issues, but the Git developers don't seem to have much interest in fixing these.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2527355/ but rather of https://stackoverflow.com/q/22630404/.

Answer (score 8):

Because a branch named `a/b/c` is stored in a file named `refs/heads/a/b/c`, which means that `refs/heads/a/b` is a directory. But if there is also a branch named `a/b`, then `refs/heads/a/b` must be a *file*, storing *that* branch.

Both things can't be true — at least on the systems Git runs on, you can only have one object on a filesystem with a given name, and it can't be both a directory and a file. So you can't have one branch with a name that is a prefix of another branch's name, when the first character they don't share is a slash.

Comment: Git could store branch named `a/b` EITHER in a file `a/b` OR in a file `a/b.file` IF a directory `a/b` exists.

Comment: @Dims except `a/b.file` is a valid branch name :) Yes, Git could have made a different design choice that would avoid the conflict, but it didn't.

Comment: So, answer to second part of my question is "impossible"?

Comment: You can try putting a suffix "-" or "/-" behind every single branch. I found that it works but didn't account for linux filesystem constraints, if they matter. Pls lemme know if what I suggested is good practice