# git: rename master to release, after having used git-flow for a while

Tags: git, github, branch, git-flow

I want to change my `master` branch to `release`, both locally and remote (on github). I know there is a question exactly for this, here an stackoverflow. My case is different, I've used `git-flow`, and there seems some cruft on github/in the git...as:

```
git branch -m master release
```

works like a charm. but then:

```
git push -u origin release
```

gets me a

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:benzkji/django-painless-redirects.git
 ! [remote rejected] release -> release (cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/release': 'refs/heads/release/0.3.5' exists; cannot crea 'refs/heads/release')
```

As far as I can tell, either this was by my bad (pushing a release branch created by `git-flow` to github, somewhen in the past), or this is by design, because the tag `0.3.5` was on the `release` branch...anyway, I dont know a way to solve this (rename an already deleted branch?! woot)

Maybe important: `master` is currently not the default branch on github, this is `develop`.

Credits - I've got the two basic lines from Scott: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/EasilyRenameYourGitDefaultBranchFromMasterToMain.aspx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ref+exists+cannot+create

Comment: The remote repository has a branch `release/0.3.5` so git cannot create `release`. Use a different name. Or remove branch `release/0.3.5` from the remote repo.

Comment: @phd true. but `release` is not the same as `release/0.3.5`? aahh, If branch b exists, no branch named b/anything can be created. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630404/git-push-refs-heads-my-subbranch-exists-cannot-create)

Comment: `git push --delete origin release/0.3.5` and it worked. no other of those release branches where around, so possibly a wrong move/push by myself, during a release... thx!

Comment: feel free to pack this in an answer that I would gladly accept :-)