# Cannot push branch after renaming and fixing error with update-refs

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push

I want to rename my local branch from `sort-rows-of-common-tables` to `develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables`, and then push it on remote as new branch. I already have a local and remote branch named `develop`.

So I tryed with

```
git branch -m develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables
```

but I got

```
error: 'refs/heads/develop' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables'
```

so I read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51535883/7658051) and succeeded to solve the problem by running

```
git update-ref -d refs/heads/develop
git branch -m develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables
```

Now I want to push `develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables` branch on remote, where this branch does not exists yet, while `develop` branch already exixts.

So I try to run

```
git push origin develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables
```

but I get

```
Enumerating objects: 7, done.    
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.    
Delta compression using up to 4 threads    
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.    
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 607 bytes | 607.00 KiB/s, done.    
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0    
remote: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables': 'refs/heads/develop' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables'    
To my_git_repo.git    
 ! [remote rejected] develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables -> develop/sort-rows-of-common-tables (failed to update ref)    
error: failed to push some refs to 'my_git_repo.git'
```

It looks like I get the same error I was getting on local, so I bet that in order to fix it on remote I have to run a command similar to the one I run before (`git update-ref -d refs/heads/develop`) which targets the remote refs.

Is it correct? If yes, how can I update the remote refs?

I have searched [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref) on the matter but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like I get the same error I was getting on local,

Yes, exactly.

> so I bet that in order to fix it on remote I have to run a command similar to the one I run before (git update-ref -d refs/heads/develop) which targets the remote refs.

Almost. You cannot run exactly this command on the remote side. But you can remove the remote branch with a push:

```
git push origin :develop
```

or

```
git push origin --delete develop
```

See the docs on [:dst](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203) and [`--delete`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--d).

Comment: Do note that this will destroy the `develop` branch on the remote and may cause data loss (When you ran `git update-ref -d refs/heads/develop` you destroyed the `develop` branch locally, if that wasn't clear). If destroying the `develop` branch from your machine and the remote is not what you intend to do, then you have to find a different prefix for your new branch that does not collide with the name of an existing branch

Comment: The danger of the step depends on how many people work with this repository and the branch `develop`.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

The problem I got came out not from a technical issue but from a logical/practical issue:

If you are working on a branch, in this case `develop`, containing some changes to your AS IS/"standard" code (let's say the AS IS code lies in `master` branch) there is no sense in developing other branches named `develop/added-something`, `develop/added-something else`, etc. because then the changes in develop would not have any "specification" characterizing them (something like `/specification-of-the-changes`).

This is properly forbidden by git, that, having an existing branch `changes`, does not allow to have branches named like `changes/specification`.

> Not functional (and forbidden by git):
>
> `develop/added-element1`
>  `develop/added-element2`
> `develop/added-element3`
>  `develop` # so what characterize this
> branch?

Instead, one should have a repository where the AS IS code lies (let's say `master`) and then many branches where the code with changes in progress lies, and these branches should follow a naming convention like `develop/added-something`, `develop/added-something-else`, where the feature that characterize them is clearly resumed in the branch name.

> Functional (and allowed by git):
>
> `develop/added-element1`
>  `develop/added-element2`
> `develop/added-element3`

Comment: honestly, i disagree with this idea. what if it's a convention to work on a `dev/user/ticket` branch, and I want to create a version of this branch with, say, code that's using legacy code? why shouldn't I be allowed to create `dev/user/ticket/legacy` and have `dev/user/ticket` hold the non-legacy code?