# Creating a (feature) subbranch results in the error "fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/feature/FeatureName': 'refs/heads/feature' exists"

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch, feature-branch

I was trying to create a feature sub-branch, `feature/featureName`.

There was some confusion amongst my team as some of us are using SourceTree and some of us are using Git Bash. In SourceTree, the subbranches get listed under `feature`, and we assumed this was a 'holder branch' which you then create subbranches under.

Thus, our process was as follows:

- Created and pushed a `main`, `development`, and `feature` branch
- Checked out to `development`
- Tried to create `feature/featureName`
- Got the error `fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/feature/FeatureName': 'refs/heads/feature' exists`

We did not understand why this was happening. Luckily we found out!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+cannot+lock+ref

Comment: none of those answers offered a simple and concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Why this error was caused:

- If there is a branch called `a`, no branch named `a/b` can be created ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630664/12094608))
- Likewise, if there is a branch called `a/b`, no branch called `a/b/c` can be created
- Likewise, if there is a branch called `a/b`, no branch named `a` can be created.

We misunderstood that to create subbranches that are categorised under `feature`, like `feature/a` or `feature/b`, **you should not create a 'holder' branch named `feature` !!!**

Instead, stick with just creating just `feature/a` and `feature/b` on their own. Git GUI's like sourcetree will then categorize these under their own header `feature`, but keep in mind that that is not an actual branch.

Hopefully this one day helps someone else who ran into this issue!