Why does Git push causes "error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:RSST/build-scripts.git'"?
I'm trying to create a new branch on github repo. I have local branche dunfell/rsbc and remote branch dunfell/rsbc/release
p@CND:~/workspace/build-scripts$ git push -f origin dunfell/rsbc 
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To github.com:RSST/build-scripts.git
 ! [remote rejected] dunfell/rsbc -> dunfell/rsbc (cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/dunfell/rsbc': 'refs/heads/dunfell/rsbc/release' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/dunfell/rsbc')
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:RSST/build-scripts.git'

Why does the existence of release branch lock up the creation of a different branch?
How do I fix this?

I believe if you have slashes in your branch names you can't also have prefixes of those names as other branch names.

I can do it locally.

I might be wrong.

I have seen plenty of projects that use that notation. x/v1.0, x/v1.1 and so on.

Yeah but then I think those would have a problem if they then just tried to use x by itself. Maybe?

I can do x/1.0 and x/1.1 but apparently not x/y/1.1. x/y and x/z are allowed. It makes no sense.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630664/616460

You can't do x/y/1.1 if you already have x/y.

It does make sense. The reason for this rule is that Git really does treat these names as folders-and-files. For example, branch dunfell/rsbc/release implies a folder dunfell, a folder rsbc, and a file release. Thus you cannot have dunfell/rsbc, because that implies, within the folder dunfell, a file rsbc — and the same path cannot denote both a folder and a file.
